# MySQL: find a match with numeric pattern

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I am trying to find rows with values matching the pattern. In my data, the pattern that I am using is 401.%, 402.%, 403.%, 404.% and 405.%. In other words, I am trying to find any floating number between 401 and 405. In addition, these number is stored as varchar. It is a string. So far, I have tried the following code, but in vain:

```
select * from my_table where my_column like '401.%'
```

and so forth.

Could you think of a way to make this work? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: So how should the `LIKE` operator treat `[1-5]`? It searches for this exact string and since you don't have one - it fails to return anything.

Comment: What you have there will only work with `my_column REGEXP '^40[1-5]\.'`

Comment: I was not clear about the intention by posting my example code (edited). I was looking for something like regular expression. I wanted to avoid repeating the like statement five times.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is very nice about converting numbers to string.  So, you can try something like this:

```
where my_column + 0 >= 401 and my_column < 406
```

Of course, this doesn't handle situations where bad characters occur after the first three characters.  But it might suffice for your purposes.

EDIT:

If you actually wanted to use an index for this, then do:

```
where my_column >= '401' and my_column < '406' and
      my_column + 0 >= 401 and my_column < 406
```

The first two string comparisons *should* take advantage of an index.

Comment: as much as I hate disagreeing with somebody of your reputation, but have you thought about waht this means? Casting ALL records to numbers - even those which will not match and forfeiting all index use?

Comment: @EugenRieck . . . Possibly a good point, but I'm not so sure that MySQL will use an index for a string of `like` comparisons connected by `or`.

Comment: If the `LIKE` does NOT start with a wildcard, the index will be used (if it exists). In this case, the ORs will be executed one after the other.

Comment: @EugenRieck . . . I can't speak to this specific instance, but I have at times had to use `union all` to get multiple conditions connected by `or`'s to use indexes.

Comment: Your edited answer looks like it combines all the good stuff - the OP should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from my_table where my_column like '401.%' or my_column like '402.%' or my_column like '403.%' or my_column like '404.%' or my_column like '405.%'
```

Should perfrom best by far ... sort of loop unrolling in SQL

Comment: Do you actually know if this query will use an index?

Comment: Just tried a quick&dirty on my localhost (Ubuntu 12.04, MySQL 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) and execution plan says "possible keys" but not "key" ... but only 1000 rows and all in cache.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, it will use index; just tested with >= 300k records on 5.5 :)